# Getting bootstrap modal to run on query failure

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to get a modal to display if a user enters a username which already exists. I am using PDO to execute the queries and I am using `if($var->rowCount() > 0)` to check whether or not the username already exists, I have also stored a variable called `$modalHead` to store the string that should be displayed for the modal head as well as `$modalMsg` as the text that should be used for the content of the modal, the use of these can be found below:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title"><?php echo $modalHead; ?></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p><?php echo $modalMsg; ?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

However, I am having issues with trying to trigger jQuery code when the PHP if statement is true. I have tried echoing the code inside of php like so:

```
echo '<script> SHOW MODAL WITH JQUERY </script>';
```

I have also tried storing a variable such as `$showModal` which either has the value true or false. I then tried to get this value using `var show = "<?php echo $showModal; ?>"` and tried to detect the value, however, that also failed to show the modal. The only luck i've had was when I got it show up earlier but the page refresh on submit stopped it from showing completely before the page reloaded. I've also played around with the idea that I could redirect the user to something like `register.php?error=...` to detect when the modal should be shown.
Any help to combat this issue would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I think you're doing this using a `POST` request, but not by using ajax, right? If so, your best option is indeed to put the variable there and use it as a conditional. But I think it'd be better if you did this using ajax. Then you can make the conditionals in javascript and have better control.

Comment: use to show `$(document).ready(function(){$('#myModal').modal('show')});`

Comment: I tried the following: `if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $modalMsg = "The entered Email Address is in the incorrect format!";
            $modalHead = "Registration Error!";
            echo "<script> $(document).ready(function(){ $('#myModal').modal('show')}); </script>";` to no avail :(

Comment: And correct, I am using a post request for the form yes

Answer (score 0):

Since the module is waiting for user input, and the checking is done server-side, the best way to do it is to do a post request using JQuery, and load the module according to the results that your PHP page returns.

In your client page ( html/js)

```
<script>
   $("#submit").click(function({
      $.ajax({
       method: "POST",
       url: "some.php",
       data: { username: "username", password: "password" }
   })
  .done(function( msg ) {
       if(msg=="0"){
         $(".modal-title").html("Registration Error!");
         $(".modal-body p").html("Username already exists!");
         $("#modal").show();   
       }else{
          //redirect here
        }
  });
 });
</script>
```

and in your some.php file

```
//Query here
//depending on query result echo 0 if error and 1 if success
```

Comment: So do you mean I can echo that jQuery within my PHP? or set a var within PHP and use a conditional statement to check which error occured?

Comment: No, you leave the modal on your client page, and depending on result from your PHP page you show the modal with the messages you would like to output. Fairly simple. the PHP page that you send your post to should act as a gateway for accepting/rejecting authentications. You cannot know the result of the authentication until the user submits their data client-side... hope this helps

Comment: I have done this, and it doesn't seem to show, i'm really stuck with why this won't work, only thing I can think of is that the page refresh it preventing the modal showing? code can be found here: https://pastebin.com/jrpXZBFZ I know for a fact that the if statement runs as i've tested an echo'd alert message in there. Thanks for the help tho :)

Comment: You shouldn't refresh... the whole point of Ajax is to avoid refreshes... could you please post some more code in your question so I can assist you?

Comment: I am just using an input with the type as submit and a form with the action being post to submit the data from the form

Comment: Edited my answer so it suits better your needs, let me know if it helps now

Comment: Oh, I also forgot to mention that both the PHP and HTML/JS are in the same file using the file extension .php in the format `<?php ?> <html> </html>` I have updated the code to fit my ids etc and it still fails to show the modal and also refreshes the page after submit, I have uploaded the code to pastebin to increase readability: https://pastebin.com/ag5ZqpPg thankyou for the continued help :)

Comment: you should separate them for Ajax to work... otherwise your modal solution wouldn't work

Comment: Okay, I made a js file in /scripts/ and named it showModal.js. I then included it within my html with `<script src="..."></script>` I have it so when the username or email is already registered, it echos '0', now I placed the above jQuery into the js file with slight modifications to fit my ids, I tested it and with the same result. The page just refreshes on the post and displays no modal. Regardless of this not working, your help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution!
I did it so on say something like a duplicate username, I did it so it redirected to the page + ?error= then gave a unique error code to each type of error. Then I used a javascript function to get the error id and then display the modal appropriate for the error. I ran this function on the body load and also added onclick to the close buttons to the modal to run a function which redirects back to the page without ?error=

Thanks everyone for their help!